# The Whole String isn't getting capitalized

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I have to create a code to capitalize the even part of string.split() and decapitalize the odd. However the code only returns the first part of the string as the result. I have some problems whith result().. I know about that but can somebody pinpoint the exact place?
The Code-

```
 def somefunc(some_string):
        x=some_string.split()
        for something in x:
            if x.index(something)%2==0:
                return something.upper()
            elif x.index(something)!=0:
                return something.lower()
        y=" ".join(x)
```

The Result-

```
myfunc("hey dude")
'HEY'
```

Comment: when you arrive to return function is ending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are returning early, do this instead:

```
def some_func(some_string):
    x = some_string.split()
    result = []
    for i, something in enumerate(x):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result.append(something.upper())
        else:
            result.append(something.lower())
    return " ".join(result)


print(some_func("hey dude"))
```

**Output**

```
HEY dude
```

Note that using index won't work, think in the case when you have duplicated words (for example `"hey hey dude"`). The solution is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the index. As an alternative you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def some_func(some_string):
    x = some_string.split()
    return " ".join([something.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else something.lower() for i, something in enumerate(x)])
```

**Note**

You could also take advantage of the fact that in Python functions are [first-class citizens](https://realpython.com/lessons/functions-are-first-class-citizens-python/) and do:

```
def some_func(some_string):
    x = some_string.split()
    cases = [str.upper, str.lower]
    return " ".join([cases[i % 2](something) for i, something in enumerate(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_method(txt):
    return ' '.join(map(lambda x: x[1].lower() if x[0] % 2 else x[1].upper(), enumerate(txt.split(' '))))


some_method('Hello Dude')
```

output:

```
'HELLO dudde'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, functions only return one value and terminate. What about if you want to have many returns? It's possible with Python generators! You have already written your function in a generator-ish style.

Here's a slightly modified generator that will go through a string, split it and yield upper case versions of even-numbered words:

```
def uppercase_even(s):
    for k, w in enumerate(s.split()):
        yield w.lower() if k % 2 else w.upper()
```

It returns (yields) lower and uppercase words alternatively. Here's how you would use it:

```
' '.join(uppercase_even('Hey My Dude'))
```

Result:

```
'HEY my DUDE'
```